# Internal ID of Button - Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I am adding a button by workflow. Later I want to hide that button, using a server script. In order to do that, I need the button's internal ID, how to get the internal id of a button in netsuite?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to hide the button with a script? If you are already using a workflow to add a button, why not use a workflow to hide the button too? There is an "Action" called 'Remove button', where you can apply an appropriate condition.

Comment: Well I just want to hide the button, I can't remove the button because I want it for transition of stage. And I want to hide it, because we don't get click event for workflow buttons. I have added another button, using Dom and I get a click event for it. After executing click event, I will mimic the clicking of workflow button and make the transition of stage.

Answer (score 0):

In my case created a form with text field to store a value and hiding the field. This may help

```
var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                title: 'Simple Form'
            });
            var field = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_file',
                type: 'file',
                label: 'Upload CSV'
            });
            form.addSubmitButton({
                label: 'Submit'
            });
           var textfield=form.addField({
                 id : 'custpage_vendor_id',
                 type : 'text',
                 label : 'Text',
                 value :'Text'
                 });
          textfield.defaultValue = 123;
          textfield.updateDisplayType({
                    displayType : serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
                  });
          context.response.writePage(form);
```

Comment: And in which way, this answer is relevant to the question? How to find internal id of custom button added by a workflow?

Comment: Netsuite allows to hide the button using Field ID.

Comment: Yes, you can hide a button using 'button.isHidden = true' in suitescript. But, in order to get the button, I need its internal ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the ID, you can simply right click on the button and click on Inspect (Microsoft Edge or Chrome).

In the dialog box opened, you can check for the field `id` and you will get the ID of the button.

Something like -

[image]

Give this a try. Let me know.

Comment: This is DOM. Button's ID in DOM is different from the button's ID that we use in SuiteScript.

Comment: @AjithV You can use JQuery within your suitescript code to get rid of the button. Will EDIT my answer later today.

Comment: Ya, that's how i have implemented it now. But DOM may vary with each netsuite update and so I am searching for an Netsuite API solution.